# Best practices for storing common directory paths in config

Tags: python, yaml, config

I am building a local job-runner that can perform a variety of maintenance tasks, from FTP to data scraping and rudimentary analysis. Since it runs based on a common file system, it needs to know where to find certain folders and files. The app won't have a database, and will rely primarily on config files in YAML format.

I'm designing the config file for these paths now, and I'm wondering if there are any best practices related to this. I tried searching but I could only find arguments between config file *formats*, not the design of their contents.

Here are methods I am debating between:

1. Nest the paths with common dictionary names, so they can be looped over recursively to generate absolute paths via os.path

   ```
   fileserver:
     drive:
       path: Shared Files
       myfolder:
         path: MyFolder
         reports:
           path: Daily Reports
           other:
             path: Other Reports
           some:
             path: Some Reports
           some2014:
             path: Some Reports 2014
           some2015:
             path: Some Reports 2015
       another-folder:
         path: 1 - Another Folder
         reports:
           path: Daily Reports
     ip: 192.168.0.0
     path: \\MYSERVER1
   ```
2. Define common dict names and add a 'parent' attribute, then use the parent attributes to walk up to the server root.

   ```
   server:
    ip: 192.168.0.0
    path: \\MYSERVER1
   drive:
    path: Shared Files
    parent: server
   myfolder:
    path: MyFolder
    parent: drive
   myreports:
    path: Daily Reports
    parent: myfolder
   somereports:
    path: Some Reports
    parent: myreports
   some2015reports:
    path: Some Reports 2015
    parent: myreports

   etc...
   ```
3. Use a placeholder convention and regex them out to absolute paths when the config file is loaded:

   ```
   server: \\MYSERVER1
   drive: [server]\Shared Files
   myfolder: [drive]\My Folder

   etc.
   ```

In a perfect world, this will be easy for a non-technical person to update when things change. Does anyone have experience implementing something like this? I don't think either of my solutions are great, and I would love to see production examples of this type of config.

Comment: It is relative and depends on how many different servers/services/files/path you need for a single config file. If the answer is 1 then I would pick your second file though if the answer is multiple then I would go with number 1. I would suggest you look at Puppet, SaltStack, Ansible, and Chef.

Comment: You should edit your question with the 3rd one because formatting doesn't show up on comments.

Comment: Thanks Emett - I've updated the question. I think the third is easiest to read, but since I am adding slashes, it doesn't give os.path an opportunity to join them and correct for mistakes. The second and third both require unique ids across the app, but is probably easier to deal with for a small set of paths. Are there any guidelines for this type of thing?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It can be a very opinionated topic. It maybe worth doing a dry run on your users and asking for feedback. My pick is number 1 but with some updates. I will add them to an answer so they keep formatting.

Comment: Emmet's answer looks cleaner. I don't know what's the problem you're trying to solve, but if there's going to be changes on the directory structure, wouldn't be better to add in the config file only the fileservers, the drives and the folders, and write a function to walk the inner directories recursively? Is there anything that prevents you to take such approach?

Comment: Thanks, charli. There are about 12,000 folders in this particular drive, so indexing them is not really a practical approach. Also, if a folder moves and changes names, walking the directories wouldn't help me find the right place anyway. Leaving this out of code also makes the code itself more extendable, for instance writing one script to handle 2+ FTP jobs based on config files.

Comment: The users voted for method 3, but I decided to adhere to the ansible convention and use double braces (e.g. {{ varname }}) instead of square brackets. Thanks everyone for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 seems to be the most extensible to me and as such is my pick.

There are some changes I would make to it as I find it a little hard to follow at a glance.

```
fileserver:
  drive:
    path: Shared Files
    myfolder:
      path: MyFolder
      reports:
        paths:
          - Daily Reports
          - Other Reports
          - Some Reports
          - Some Reports 2014
          - Some Reports 2015
    another-folder:
      path: 1 - Another Folder
      reports:
        paths:
          - Daily Reports
  ip: 192.168.0.0
  path: \\MYSERVER1
```

Comment: Thanks, Emett! I think the case against the paths array is positional dependence - if the names of those folders change or the order changes in the config file, they need to be updated in code as well, since they'll be accessed with something like config["fileserver"]["drive"]["reports"]["paths"][3]. I agree though that my example is difficult to read and probably intimidating for a non-technical person trying to update the settings.